# 132.5mm dropout spacing with a 130mm hub AFTER it has already been used with a 135mm hub

Tags: steel, dropouts

I have a steel frame with 132.5 mm dropout spacing, the manufacturer claims it is compatible with 130mm or 135mm hubs...but I wonder if it will remain compatible with 130mm hubs AFTER it has been run with 135mm hubs?  My concern is the 135mm hub will stretch the dropouts so it will no longer "work" with 130mm hubs. Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Don't worry about it!

Steel is inherently a springy material and you will find the dropouts spring back to their original location once the wheel is removed.

In order to permanently re-set the dropout width, you need to bend the steel past its elastic limit. You can look up "cold setting" by Sheldon Brown or whoever you like if you're interested.

Comment: To add to this, I once had a rear hub with 132.5mm spacing. This was a cheat, of sorts, to maximize the spoke bracing angle, particularly on the drive side. For reference, this was the Alchemy Orc rear hub by Jeremy Parfitt, later bought by Wheels Manufacturing, but discontinued. Anyway, it fit just fine in regular road frames.

Comment: thanks! I did not realize cold setting worked in both directions.

Comment: @mancini0 at risk of being pedantic, Joe's point was that you are *not* going to cold set a steel frame by bending each of the stays a mere 1.25mm.